i downloaded GUI for ubuntu 20.04.5 on raspi 4, but the mouse and keyboard stopped
I installed ubuntu-desktop on my raspi 4 but when everything was done and the GUI was installed, I rebooted the raspi from the tty to get access for the GUI, when it ran, neither the mouse nor the keyboard were working, i can see the user, but I'm unable to login
